# MYSQL: can BULK select can still return array of results from inputs of same value?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> select Name from Type where id in (8,8);

+------------------+
| Name             |
+------------------+
| PUBLISHER        |
+------------------+
```

It only returns 1 value.

Is there a way it can return 2 PUBLISHER ? since i have 2 inputs, i need that for the forEach in the js code.
Thanks !

Comment: You can use the same variable at multiple places.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the previous answers, but perhaps a little more reflective of the behavior you're expecting, and not requiring the entire query be repeated for each value in the list, another option would be something like this:

```
SELECT t.Name 
FROM (
   SELECT 8 AS id
   UNION ALL SELECT 8
) AS p
INNER JOIN `Type` AS t ON p.id = t.id
;
```

Comment: As per [Nested Loop Join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/nested-loop-joins.html) algorithm used by MySQL, this approach does not change the fact that there will still be two lookups on `id = 8`. Infact all the three answers will have nearly same costs.. worth comparing Explain plans..although on first look, it does give an illusion of neater trick :-) +1

Comment: Oh, I have no doubt there will end up being multiple lookups for the same id value, but it _might_ be slightly less costly than outright unions of duplicate queries, since the only thing actually unioned is the constants and then all those are carried out in a single join. Even without any performance benefits, as long as it does not turn out to be more costly, this version would probably be worth it for the easier maintenance (additional values only require another `UNION ALL SELECT value` line added, and changes to the main query will not need replicated across multiple unions).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to break this into individual Select queries for each `id` value and then do a `Union All`.  You can easily prepare the query in a loop for each `id` value input:

```
Select Name From Type Where id = 8
Union All
Select Name From Type Where id = 8
```

Comment: @user3552178 I don't think so, if proper indexes are there. MySQL indeed converts `OR` to Union for Optimization many times .give it a try

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
select Name from Type where id in (8,8)
```

Is syntaxically equivalent to:

```
select Name from Type where id = 8
```

The number of items in the `IN` operator does not tell anything about the number of records in the resultset. It just tells your RDBMS to return all records that match any of the value listed at the right of `IN` operator.

The results that you are getting do indicate that there is a single record in the table that has `id = 8`.

A solution to get the output that you expected would be to use `UNION ALL`:

```
select Name from Type where id = 8
union all
select Name from Type where id = 8
```